# How to run unit tests on methods in an Android activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, android-activity, junit

Working on an Android app in Android Studio. I am trying to write unit tests for methods in my activity LoginPage. However, I am clearly missing something big. I figure that I would need to make an instance of LoginPage and call the methods from that instance to test them. However, when I try to do this, I get a NullPointerException for anytime I tried to access that object. How do I test these Activity-specific methods if I can't have an instance of the Activity? I figured one solution would be to make every data field in the Activity static, but I feel like that would be considered sloppy coding.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class LoginPageTest {

    LoginPage myObjectUnderTest;


    public static final String FAKE_USERNAME = "rodneyram";


    @Before
    public void onLaunch() { myObjectUnderTest = new LoginPage();
    }


    @Test
    public void username_EditText_Test() {

        //Test if the usernameID editText widget correctly gets the written username.

        myObjectUnderTest.usernameID.setText("");
        myObjectUnderTest.usernameID.append(FAKE_USERNAME);
        String testString = myObjectUnderTest.usernameID.getText().toString();
        assertEquals(testString, FAKE_USERNAME);
    }

     @After
        public void tearDown() {
            myObjectUnderTest = null;
     }

}
```

My error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.donapp.LoginPageTest.password_EditText_Test(LoginPageTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) ``
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't test android APIs with unit tests, but you need to do instrumental UI tests instead.

That's because you need to get access to your activity and UI elements like in your case the `EditText`.

unit tests can be written under `test` java package, and instrumental tests can be written under `androidTest` package.

In order to get an activity instance in your test, you need to create a Rule using @Rule annotation:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule mMainActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        MainActivity.class);
```

Here I am assuming that your activity is named as `MainActivity`

You can then access UI widgets using Espresso `ViewMatchers` and then you can apply actions on them using `ViewActions`.

For instance, to check if your `usernameID` EditText text String contains a particular String:

```
onView(withId(R.id.usernameID)).check(matches(withText(containsString("SOME_TEXT"))));
```

Demo instrumental test class

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class EditTextTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule mMainActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
            MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void editTextTest() {
       onView(withId(R.id.editText_main)).check(matches(withText(containsString("SOME_TEXT"))));
    }


}
```

Check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso) for further help.

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests are not for testing the UI, you usually use them to test some business logic. For your case you could extract the append Method

```
public String appendText(String textToAppend) {
 String userName = "";
 return userName.append(textToAppend);
}
```

and then write a Unit test for this method:

```
@Test
public void appendTextTest() {
    String testString = appendText(FAKE_USERNAME);
    assertEquals(testString, FAKE_USERNAME);
}
```

If you really want to test the UI consider some UI testing tool like Espresso.